# $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. Show that $f$ bounded $\iff $ $n>n_0\implies |f_n(x)|\le K$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $f_n:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions that converge uniformly to $f:Ẍ\to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is bounded $\iff$ there exists $K>0$ and $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le K$ for all $x\in X$, when $n>n_0$

What I did:

If $|f_n(x)|\le M$ when $n>n_0$, take (set of $f_n(x)$ when $n>n_0$)$\cup$(set of $f_n(x)$ when $n\le n_0$)

Since the second set is finite, and the first is bounded, there will be a maximum element and the function will be bounded.

Now, if we suppose that $f$ is bounded by $Q$, then choose $\epsilon = M$, so that $n>n_0$ implies:

$$|f_n(x)| = |f_n(x)-f(x)+f(x)|\le |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)|\le M+Q $$

our $K$ is $M+Q$

am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks fine to me except the first two lines which I feel unnecessary.

Since $f_n\to f $ uniformly so $|f_n-f|<M$ (You chose $\epsilon=M)$ so $\exists n_0$ such that $|f_n-f|<M$ forall $n>n_0$.

Then for $n>n_0$;$|f_n(x)|\le |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)|$.

The rest you have done fine.